# What's the non-aggregate type in [c++]?

Tags: c++, types, initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Aggregates and POD's and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)

I got an error,

```
Non-aggregate type 'b2FixtureDef' cannot be initialized with an initializer list
```

during compiling this,

```
        b2FixtureDef    def = 
        {
            .shape      =   shape,
            .density    =   1.0f,
        }
```

C++ source. (Clang, Mac OS X)

What's the non-aggregate type?

---

The type `b2FixtureDef` is one of Box2D class defined as `struct` with default initializer.

```
struct b2FixtureDef
{
    b2FixtureDef()
    {
        shape = NULL;
        userData = NULL;
        friction = 0.2f;
        restitution = 0.0f;
        density = 0.0f;
        filter.categoryBits = 0x0001;
        filter.maskBits = 0xFFFF;
        filter.groupIndex = 0;
        isSensor = false;
    }
    const b2Shape* shape;
    void* userData;
    float32 friction;
    float32 restitution;
    float32 density;
    bool isSensor;
    b2Filter filter;
};
```

Comment: Read this FAQ entry : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special

Comment: so did you figure it out or not?

Comment: @celavek I got it. It was a perfect description.

Comment: That initialisation syntax is not valid C++. Use your constructors and ctor-initializers.